# Using persistent variable on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, persistent

I have been trying to get this persistent variable to work and I'm not sure what is wrong. The idea is that I enter a value i.e. 'annualbalance(2000)'. 
If the value is less than £5000 the interest will be 5% and if its greater than or equal to £5000 then the interest will be 10%. I want to be able to run the function manually as many times as I like until I get a value above, let's say £5100 hence why I have not used a loop.

```
function annualbalance(x)

persistent annualbalance;
if isempty(annualbalance)
    annualbalance = 0;
elseif annualbalance < 5000
    annualbalance = annualbalance * 1.05
elseif annualbalance >= 5000
     annualbalance = annualbalance * 1.10
end
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand your choice of a persistent variable and how you plan to use the function. First year you call `annualbalance(2000)` which returns 2100. What do you do for the next year? Call `annualbalance(2000)` again? Call `annualbalance(2100)`? Not sure what you want.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear initially, the idea to to replace x with the new value. first: annualbalance(2000) second: annualbalnce(2100) etc

Comment: Then take the answer Cris Luengo provided. There is absolutely no reason to insert persistence.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to use a persistent variable here. But you do want to output your result. My guess is you want this function:

```matlab
function x = annualbalance(x)
if x < 5000
   x = x * 1.05
elseif x >= 5000
   x = x * 1.10
end
```

You can call this function repeatedly like so:

```matlab
moneys = 1000;   % your start value
moneys = annualbalance(moneys);
moneys = annualbalance(moneys);
moneys = annualbalance(moneys);
moneys = annualbalance(moneys);
moneys = annualbalance(moneys);
moneys = annualbalance(moneys);
moneys           % display the amount you have now after 6 years
```

If you want to see how many years you need to wait to get a certain amount, you can use a loop as follows:

```matlab
moneys = 1000;   % your start value
years = 0;       % keeps track of time
while moneys < 5100  % target amount
   moneys = annualbalance(moneys);
   years = years + 1;
end
fprintf('I have %f money after %f years\n', moneys, years);
```

Comment: Thank you! However I can do this very same example using loops and manually already. I'm just struggling how to use the persistent variable. I purposefully chose to use the persistent variable.

Comment: @DevinaArts: Then you need to explain what you want to accomplish, because if it's not what is in this answer, I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try to define an output variable and delare the variable (not the function) as persistent:

```
function annualbalance(x)

persistent out;
if isempty(out)
    out = 0;
elseif out < 5000
    out = out * 1.05
elseif out >= 5000
     out = out * 1.10
end
```

That is not a good way to code it, however. The variable `out` will not be accessible outside the `annualbalance` function. Perhaps it would be better to work with an output variable. Also, your function receives `x` as an input argument, but `x` appears nowhere in the function. You should also check that out.

Comment: Change 'x' to 'out' in the function header